# Rails Authentication with has_secure_password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

How would I create sessions with rails 3 has_secure_password? I've checked out http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html.

And none of it is really specific. do I have to use sessions method? What is the community standard? I do not want to use Devise/Cancan. 
I only need simple authorization/authentication based on cookies.

Should I be storing User objects in cookies?
Would the password be vulnerable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the money to spend, Railscasts Pro covers this in detail using has_secure_password in Episode 250 Revised, [Authentication from Scratch (revised)](http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch-revised)

---

There is also a slightly older version of the screencast that is Free and includes a detailed [ASCIIcast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch?view=asciicast). The sessions portion might be useful for you to read or watch.

Comment: Rails needs more documentation for authentication/authorization. Feels bad that I had to watch a railscast(not free, although it was excellent) to get my answer.

Comment: In 2023 this video is still pretty legit, granted a few things need to be updated for the Rails 7 way (such as strong params, and forms), but overall solid base principles and super helpful. Thanks for this!

Answer (score 3):

Check out this tutorial by Michael Hartl on Chapter 8. He did a good job explaining the implementation of using has_secured

http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book

basically you will need a password field AND a password_confirmation field AND a password_digest field in your user model. by calling has_secure_password in your model, whenever password confirmation is valid, a password_digest will be generated. You can log in users in your sessions controller by checking:

```
if user and user.authenticate(password)
  // sign_in_user
else
  // return error message
end
```

A remember_token will also be needed in your model field for identifying users in cookies.
You can return the remember_token on authentication and set it to the session function in rails, example:

```
user = User.find_by_email(email)
session[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
```

Comment: note that the password and password_confirmation fields are variables that are not written to the database

Comment: could we say that password and password_confirmation are not in the model, only on the html page?

Comment: @KevinZhao You could say that. Ultimately only a encrypted password is stored in the model. The view is only used to collect the information necessary to construct this password digest.